# Using SetWindowPos with UWP (or metro) apps has no effect

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

I'm trying to control Skype App (UWP, not Desktop) from my WPF application.
I can launch Skype ([this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2015/10/24/launching-windows-store-apps-programmatically/) helped a lot! Thanks, Pavel!) but cannot move, maximize, minimize it's window.
This is the relevant part of the code:

```
    uint pid = 0;
    try
    {
        // Launch Skype and get it's process id
        pid = MetroLauncher.LaunchApp("Microsoft.SkypeApp_14.42.60.0_x64__kzf8qxf38zg5c");
    }
    catch (global::System.Exception e)
    {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "global::System.Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }

    Process skypeProc = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.Id == pid).SingleOrDefault();

    IntPtr handleSkype = skypeProc.MainWindowHandle;

    // Remove maximize and minimize controls.
    int oldStyle = GetWindowLong(handleSkype, GWL_STYLE);

    SetWindowLongPtr(new HandleRef(null, handleSkype), GWL_STYLE, oldStyle & ~WS_MINIMIZEBOX & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~WS_THICKFRAME); 

    // Get screen dimensions
    int ScreenX = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int ScreenY = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    // Try to alter Skype's main window as I want...
    SetWindowPos(handleSkype, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, ScreenX, ScreenY, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_DRAWFRAME);
```

A similar code worked perfectly with Skype for Desktop and other desktop apps.
Do UWP windows work differently from desktop apps ones?

Comment: Those APIs are kinda fiddly.  You may want to consider using _Microsoft UI Automation_

Comment: I've been trying to find out how your answer could help me for several hours without success. Thank you anyway, MickyD.

Comment: It’s a comment not an answer

Comment: I've been trying to find out how your comment could help me for several hours without success. Thank you anyway, MickyD.

Comment: Hi Juanjo, currently, UWP does not support adjust window with `SetWindowPos` method.

Comment: Thank you, Nico. Yours is a definitive answer (or comment :)

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT thank you for this information, is there an alternative way to move control (e. g. move, resize) UWP apps?